# PHP/MySQL sort numbers with speed units

Tags: php, mysql

I've got many records with speed units in a large MySQL database like `123.4MB/s` and `364KB/s`.

I want to sort them in descending order, however the units are pretty annoying.

I have already tried the following however it didn't work:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY speed DESC LIMIT 20")
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Editing the whole database is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN speed LIKE '%KB/s' THEN CAST(speed AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        WHEN speed LIKE '%MB/s' THEN CAST(speed AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 1024
    END
DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If such query is common and not so many duplications on speed, try create an index on speed.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can use this solution -

```
...ORDER BY IF(LOCATE('MB', speed), speed * 1024, speed * 1)
```